# Sleep in a while loop caused no response

Tags: perl

I wrote a `sleep` in a `while` loop.  It's a very simple code but didn't work.

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

&main();
sub main()
{
print "hello\n";

while(1)                    # #1
{   
      print "go~  ";
      sleep 2;      
}
}
```

---

If commenting out #1, "go~" is printed; otherwise, it is just waiting without any "go~" to print.
My intention is to do something periodically.

Could anyone give some explanation/hint?

Comment: Change that `print "go~ ";` to `print "go~ \n";` and try again.

Comment: @LeeDuhem yes that will work. i checked. Buffer problem

Comment: Perl is not C, C++, or Java, you do not need to define a `main()` then call it.

Comment: @TejasPatel It looks like this problem is quite common. Should we suggest newbie to use `say` instead of `print`?

Comment: Yet another case of [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding new line after go~

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    &main();
    sub main()
    {
    print "hello\n";

    while(1)                    # #1
    {
          print "go~\n";
          sleep(2);
    }
    }
```

Explanation why it works:
The stdout stream is buffered, so will only display what's in the buffer after it reaches a newline (or when it's told to). You didn't use newline so the the text will get appended to buffer until the size of buffer.

If you don't want to use newline than add following lines at begining

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

#!/usr/bin/perl

$dir = "/home/tazim/Videos/perl/*";

my@files = glob($dir);

foreach(@files){
print $_."\n";

sleep(2);

}